# Get % of Each item from List<ListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to calculate percentage for each item from list against total item count. Assume my list contains three items:

1. yes, having count 0
2. no, having count 0
3. can't say, having count 1

optionsList.Count: 3

```
foreach (ListItem opt in optionsList)
{
    double cnt = Convert.ToDouble(opt.Value);
    double totalCnt = Convert.ToDouble(optionsList.Count);
    double percentage = Math.Truncate((cnt/ totalCnt) * 100);

    results.InnerHtml += percentage.ToString() + " % " + opt.Text + " <br/>" + " <br/>";
}
```

Output:

- 0 % Yes
- 0 % No
- 33 % Can't Say

In above result if yes and no are 0 then result should be 100% but it display 33%.

Comment: If 'Yes' is 0 and you divide 0 by 3 you will get 0 in the end. Same thing goes for 'No' .I think you don't know what you want here.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to divide by the sum of the values in the optionsList, not the count as there will always only be 3 elements

Comment: You are dividing the value(1) by the count of options(3) so that makes (0,33)  and multiply by 100. So 33% is your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The key point here is that you should divide by SUM of count member, not the count of list entries. In your example totalCount was always 3, so
1/3*100 = 33%. actually totalCount should be 0 + 0 + 1 so you end up with
1/1*100 = 100%.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
                testList.Add(new Test { name = "yes", count = 1 });
                testList.Add(new Test { name = "no", count = 0 });
                testList.Add(new Test { name = "can't say", count = 3 });


                var totalCount = testList.Sum(c => c.count);

                foreach(var item in testList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", (decimal)item.count / totalCount * 100, item.name));
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to point out the key difference - dividing by the sum of answers rather than the sum of options...